# Powershell replace last two occurrences of a '/' in file path with '.'

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a filepath, and I'm trying to remove the last two occurrences of the `/` character into `.` and also completely remove the '{}' via Powershell to then turn that into a variable.

So, turn this:

```
xxx-xxx-xx\xxxxxxx\x\{xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx}\xxxxx\xxxxx
```

Into this:

```
xxx-xxx-xx\xxxxxxx\x\xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx
```

I've tried to get this working with the replace cmdlet, but this seems to focus more on replacing all occurrences or the first/last occurrence, which isn't my issue.  Any guidance would be appreciated!

Edit:

So, I have an excel file and i'm creating a powershell script that uses a for each loop over every row, which amounts to thousands of entries.  For each of those entries, I want to create a secondary variable that will take the full path, and save that path minus the last two slashes.  Here's the portion of the script that i'm working on:

```
Foreach($script in $roboSource)
   {
    $logFileName = "$($script.a).txt".Replace('(?<=^[^\]+-[^\]+)-','.')
   }
```

$script.a will output thousands of entries in this format: 
xxx-xxx-xx\xxxxxxx\x{xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx}\xxxxx\xxxxx
Which is expected.

I want $logFileName to output this:
xxx-xxx-xx\xxxxxxx\x\xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx

I'm just starting to understand regex, and I believe the capture group between the parenthesis should be catching at least one of the '\', but testing attempts show no changes after adding the replace+regex.

Please let me know if I can provide more info.

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside: Note that the `.Replace` method (of type `[string]`) uses _literal_ substring replacement - no regexes supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 2-step approach is simplest in this case:

```
# Input string.
$str = 'xxx-xxx-xx\xxxxxxx\x\{xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx}\xxxxx\xxxxx'

# Get everything before the "{"
$prefix = $str -replace '\{.+'

# Get everything starting with the "{", remove "{ and "}", 
# and replace "\" with "."
$suffix = $str.Substring($prefix.Length) -replace '[{}]' -replace '\\', '.'

# Output the combined result (or assign to $logFileName)
$prefix + $suffix
```

---

If you wanted to do it with a single `-replace` operation (with nesting), things get more complicated:

Note: This solution requires PowerShell *Core* (v6.1+)

```
$str -replace '(.+)\{(.+)\}(.+)',
  { $_.Groups[1].Value + $_.Groups[2].Value + ($_.Groups[3].Value -replace '\\', '.') }
```

Also see the elegant PS-Core-only `-split` based solution with a *negative* index (to split only a fixed number of tokens off the *end*) in [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58844675/45375).

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Alex1088; my pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in two fairly simply `-replace` operations:

- Remove `{` and `}`
- Replace the last two `\`:

```
$str = 'xxx-xxx-xx\xxxxxxx\x\{xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx}\xxxxx\xxxxx'
$str -replace '[{}]' -replace '\\([^\\]*)\\([^\\]*)$','.$1.$2'
```

The second pattern matches:

```
\\         # 1 literal '\'
(          # open first capture group
  [^\\]*   # 0 or more non-'\' characters
)          # close first capture group
\\         # 1 literal '\'
(          # open second capture group
  [^\\]*   # 0 or more non-'\' characters
)          # close second capture group
$          # end of string
```

Which we replace with the first and second capture group values, but with `.` before, instead of `\`: `.$1.$2`

---

If you're using PowerShell Core version 6.1 or newer, you can also take advantage of right-to-left `-split`:

```
($str -replace '[{}]' -split '\\',-3) -join '.'
```

`-split '\\',-3` has the same effect as `-split '\\',3`, but splitting from the right rather than the left.

Comment: Understood re the desire to explicitly signal "not `\ `". It turns out that's actually _required_ - what I suggested earlier (non-greedy duplication with `.+?`) doesn't actually work in this case. Given that the strings between `\ ` instances are by definition _nonempty_, however, it's better to use `[^\\]+` than `[^\\]*` for conceptual clarity.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$str='xxx-xxx-xx\xxxxxxx\x\{xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx}\xxxxx\xxxxx'

#remove  bracket and split for get array
$Array=$str -replace '[{}]' -split '\\'

#take all element except 2 last elements, and concat after last elems
"{0}.{1}.{2}" -f ($Array[0..($Array.Length -3)] -join '\'), $Array[-2], $Array[-1]
```

Comment: In PowerShell 6 you could do `($str -replace '[{}]' -split '\\',-3) -join '.'` :D